# Unable to join a domain in my virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, vmware-server

I have two VMs using Vmware. Windows 2012 R2 is installed on both VMs. First VM I called **comp1** and have installed AD DS and DNS features, and I am trying to have the second VM called **comp2** join the domain.

Comp1 get this error:

[image]

and comp2 get this when I try to join:

[image]

I tried to ping VMs and it works fine.

Comment: Was comp1 promoted to a domain controller and the AD forest created properly?

Comment: Yes I think i promoted comp1 to a domain controller. [AD Users and Computers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g75xr.png)

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22622.building-your-first-domain-controller-on-2012-r2.aspx